# Stacked Bar Chart with individual spacings to compare pairs of bars

Tags: charts

I would like to plot a stacked `BarChart`

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {6, 4}], ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

with modified `BarSpacing`, so I get 3 pairs of stacked bars being more closely together, so it is implied they belong together and can be compared more easily.

I am very happy about your help :) Thx in advance 
Kilian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Pre-processing input data into a form acceptable for [`RectangleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RectangleChart.html) we get finer control on the size of the gaps between groups of bars.

The function `prep` below takes two arguments: The first argument controls the size of gaps between groups and the second controls group size.

```
prep[w_: 1/4, n_:2] := Flatten[Riffle[Partition[Thread[{1, #}] & /@ #, n], {{{{w, 0}}}}], 
      1] &
RectangleChart[prep[]@data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image]

```
RectangleChart[prep[1]@data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image]

```
RectangleChart[prep[1, 3]@data, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

I don't think this can be achieved using `BarSpacing`.
You can partition input data into groups of two and insert `Missing[]` between groups:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {6, 4}];
BarChart[Flatten[Riffle[Partition[data, 2], Missing[]], 1], 
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot :) I was searching for something this! Best regards

Comment: @Kilian, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Only in case you whish to have bigger space between pairs ...

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {6, 4}];
BarChart[Flatten[
  Riffle[Partition[data, 2], Missing[]] /. 
   Missing[] -> {Missing[], Missing[], Missing[]}, 1], 
 BarSpacing -> Medium, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

Comment: Not a bad hack!  But this can be done quite a bit more concisely: `BarChart[Riffle[data, Unevaluated[{}, {}, {}], 3], BarSpacing -> Medium, 
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]`